# Module not found: You attempted to import which falls outside of the project src/ directory

Tags: reactjs, filepath

I am trying to add image to the carousal from the public/image folder in the carosal.js file.
My component tree looks like this: [image: component tree]

I wrote " ../../public/image/cover1.png"

but getting an error saying:

Module not found: You attempted to import ../../public/image/cover1.png which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming this is a create react app project, the public folder is served statically, so instead of directly trying to import the image from the public folder you can simply reference the image in your code without the relative path.

As an example, you could do the following

`<img src="image/cover1.png" />`

This way you are not actually importing the image file like its a module, but instead you are having the server serve it the browser statically.

Comment: great! Please consider upvoting and accepting if this has solved your issue

Comment: Hi Chaim, I have another thread that I need to get the answer badly! can I send you the link?